# SQL Server Query Plan for Multiple INSERT Statements versus Multiple Queries

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-execution-plan

If I have to insert 100-500 rows of data, I'm trying to figure out the best method in terms of performance (network latency, sql query plans, execution, etc.)

For simplicity, see the image below with only 2 inserts.  I would be adding many more fields/values in reality (and have different types of queries), but hopefully it illustrates my concern.

Is it better to batch 100s of these statements in one query and send it back to SQL server, or should I send one query at a time.  With one big query, is it compiling/caching a query plan for the 'whole thing' or does it do it for each 'statement' and therefore reusing a query plan regardless of how I piece together the query (with smaller query parts)?

[image]

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for code. For including  execution plans, there's [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/). To address your question, what will make far more difference is whether these statements are wrapped in a single transaction or not. When not, they have to be committed individually, which is much slower. Network overhead is generally a lesser problem. In both cases a plan would be cached, but it's not relevant because this `INSERT` is trivial. To submit more data in one go, see also table value constructors and bulk copy.

Comment: They are wrapped in a transaction.  So you are saying I don't have to send one query at a time to get SQL to do the best it can query plan caching wise?  I can amend question if needed, but I am doing 2 loops.  For example, maybe looping 500 people, each person has batch of inserts (shown above).  So each person will be wrapped in a transaction and the queries used in entire process are 'same' but could be grouped differently in one big batch per person.